# GCP: Update Drive Storage Quota for a user managed service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, quota

I'm trying to learn how to increase the "Drive storage quota" for a GCP user-managed service account (xxxxxxx-@quickstart-xxxx752989693.iam.gserviceaccount.com). Our app is returning the following error.

**Error Logs**

> GoogleApiException: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError The user's Drive
> storage quota has been exceeded. [403] Errors [ Message[The user's
> Drive storage quota has been exceeded.] Location[ - ]
> Reason[storageQuotaExceeded] Domain[usageLimits] ]

[image]

The only quotas I can find are Queries per 100 seconds, but nothing related to the number of files or amount of storage. Does anyone know how to resolve the error above?

Any help is GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Google Drive is not part of Google Cloud. Go to your Google Drive account. https://www.google.com/drive/

Comment: Hey @JohnHanley, Thanks for the comment. It is a "user-managed service account". To my knowledge, I can't log into drive using that account. Do you have any suggestions for increasing the limit specifically for a "service account"?

Comment: Service Accounts do not have Google Drive accounts. You must have granted the service account access to a user account. Your drive quota is most likely a hard limitation. Increasing storage space means purchasing more storage. https://one.google.com/about/plans